# unable to get frame size of a Subview that I have put on UItableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have been trying to get the frame of ImageView That I have put on UItableView Cell.

**Situation:**
I am using Story board. And on one of the viewController I have added the UITable programatically.

I separately created a XIB file of a UITableViewCell and on them I put some UIviews like Lable, ImageViews etc. Since my app is for all the devices including the iPad, I have used the Autolayout(which I have used First time). I used the autolayout and subviews are adjusting/changing their height **&** size according to the device perfectly, as I check on device.

Only problem is I need the the width of one of the SubViews of my UItableView cell. Inspite the  view is growing and adjusting as I have made on XIB using the autolayout it Gives me Wrong width of the SubView. no matter on which device I run, It gives me the same width every time, the width it got on the XIB file.

Is there something I am missing regarding the Autolayouts or UItableView Cells? 
Please let me know if some Information is missing in the Question

I have added the Image for reference. The UIimageView in middle

[image: Pic of the UItableView cell xib]

Comment: add constraints for fixing width of imageview in xib

Comment: @johnykumar I have already Added the Constraints, Thats why it is adjusting correctly. but gives me false width when I NSLOG. it gives me the Width I have given to it in xib file

Comment: Where are you trying to get the frame of you subview? In which class, and inside which method?

Comment: In the method cell for index before returning the cell

Comment: It works for me if I put  [cell layoutIfNeeded]; before I inspect the size.

Comment: @rdelmar Didn't work ;(

Comment: Just check that if you are printing the size before viewWillAppear or not. If before viewWillAppear then size that will print will be of size in xib or storyboard.

Comment: @iHulk I tried both options, but no success